# Correct way to return a SQL DataRow for field population

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following scenario which I've been using to return a single row from a SQL database. After I've returned the data I'm simply using it to populate fields on my web form.

Example database class:

```
public class DBAccess
{
    public DataTable ReturnContactInfo(int userID)
    {
        // executes a stored procedure, populates a datatable, then returns it
    }
}
```

Example using the class to populate a theoretical customer name field:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!isPostBack)
    {
        DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
        DataTable dt =  db.ReturnContactInfo(1);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
           customerName.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["customerName"]);
        }
     }
}
```

Is there a better or more efficient way of doing this ("this" being returning a single data row to pull data from)? This approach certainly works, but it's a bit cumbersome to have to type dt.Rows[0][string] when I'm always and only going to be working with the row at index 0. Please keep in mind that I'd like to be able to keep all the data layer stuff extracted to a single class. Which (from what I understand) means I cannot use a SqlDataReader because it has to be closed when finished so I can't return it from my data layer class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a class with the members you want as properties. Then populate and return that object. You can make this simple using tools like "dapper":

```
public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
{
     return connection.Query<Customer>("getCustomer",
         new {id}, // <=== param
         commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).Single();
}
```

Then:

```
var cust = GetCustomer(12345);
string name = cust.Name;
```

Now:

- it is clear we have a single object
- the members on the object are obvious and well-types
- you avoid a lot of overhead from DataTable

Comment: What if my application has dozens and dozens of stored procedures. Would you create a class for each procedure? And of course each procedure could return dozens of columns

Comment: @newkid91 I would create a class for each *entity*, sure. I hate to be tw bearer of bad news, but that is best practice here; DataTable is a hack. For a throwaway query there is a untyped `Query` in dapper that uses `dynamic`.

Comment: @Marc Gravell could you please explain further the first section of code?

Comment: @Marc Gravell not bad news. I'm not looking for a lazy way out. My example is the lazy way. I'm looking for the correct way.

Comment: @newKid91 consider: defining a class is a lot more robust than all that `["customerName"]`. I submit that your current approach is fundamentally risky.

Comment: @newKid91 k; `.Query<T>(...)` is an extension method from "dapper" that simplifies data access to classes. It takes a command-text (or a SPROC name since we are specifying CommandType.StoredProcedure), and an object to represent the parameters. In this case, I'm using an anon-type to represent o parameters and assuming there is an `@id int` parameter. It returns a sequence (`IEnumerable<T>`) of populated records, but we expect exactly one, so the LINQ `Single()` method asserts that for us.

Answer (score 0):

Why not return a DataRow instead of a DataTable if you know you're only going to return 1 row?

Comment: What if it's empty? DataRow dr = new DataRow(). If I return that then try to access a key will it throw an exception?

Comment: Return null if it's empty and check for null.  No matter what you do, you'll have to do some kind of check and handle the case if the row is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code generator that generates my data access code, one class per stored procedure. One of the options is that you can specify that its result set consists of a single row. Usage is simple: the generated code is invoked via a wrapper method that enforces whatever constraints the usage contract requires, thus:

```
    public DataRow GetPatientData( int patientID )
    {
        dbo_GetPatientData67 sp = new dbo_GetPatientData( CONNECT_STRING_ID ) ;
        int                  rc = sp.Exec( patientID ) ;
        DataRow              dr = sp.ResultSet ;

        if ( dr == null ) throw new InvalidOperationException("nothing returned from stored procedure.") ;
        return dr ;
    }
```

Here's the essentials of data access code:

```
/* generated code. do not change -- generated code */
public class dbo_GetPatientData
{

  public int     ReturnCode { get ; private set ; }
  public DataRow ResultSet { get ; private set ; }

  public int Exec(  int? @iPatientID )
  {
    using ( SqlConnection  conn = new SqlConnection( this._connectString ) )
    using ( SqlCommand     cmd  = conn.CreateCommand() )
    using ( SqlDataAdapter sda  = new SqlDataAdapter( cmd ) )
    {
      cmd.CommandText = STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME ;
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;

      //
      // 1. @iPatientID
      //
      // required
        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter( @"@iPatientID" , SqlDbType.Int ) ;
        if ( @iPatientID == null )
        {
          p1.Value = System.DBNull.Value ;
        }
        else
        {
          p1.Value = @iPatientID ;
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add( p1 ) ;

      // add return code parameter
      SqlParameter pReturnCode = new SqlParameter() ;
      pReturnCode.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int ;
      pReturnCode.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue ;
      cmd.Parameters.Add( pReturnCode ) ;

      DataSet ds = new DataSet() ;

      conn.Open() ;
      sda.Fill( ds ) ;
      conn.Close() ;

      DataTable dt    = ( ds.Tables.Count > 0 ? ds.Tables[0] : null ) ;
      this.ResultSet  = ( dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0 ? dt.Rows[0] : null ) ;
      this.ReturnCode = (int) pReturnCode.Value ;


    }

    return this.ReturnCode ;

  }

}
```

Now you only have a DataRow to deal with (though, its associated DataTable/DataSet, etc. are still there if you need them). Adding extension methods to the `DataRow` class eliminates a lot of the tedium of downcasting each column to the correct type. I'd rather write:

```
int? x = dr.CastAsIntNullable( "myColumn" ) ;
```

than the usual boilerplate.

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
{

    #region downcast to DateTime

    public static DateTime CastAsDateTime( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toDateTime( row[index] ) ;
    }
    public static DateTime CastAsDateTime( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toDateTime( row[columnName] ) ;
    }

    public static DateTime? CastAsDateTimeNullable( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toDateTimeNullable( row[index] );
    }
    public static DateTime? CastAsDateTimeNullable( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toDateTimeNullable( row[columnName] ) ;
    }

    #region conversion helpers

    private static DateTime toDateTime( object o )
    {
        DateTime value = (DateTime)o;
        return value;
    }

    private static DateTime? toDateTimeNullable( object o )
    {
        bool  hasValue = !( o is DBNull );
        DateTime? value    = ( hasValue ? (DateTime?) o : (DateTime?) null ) ;
        return value;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion downcast to DateTime

    #region downcast to byte[]

    public static byte[] CastAsByteArray( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toByteArray( row[index] );
    }
    public static byte[] CastAsByteArray( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toByteArray( row[columnName] );
    }

    #region conversion helpers

    private static byte[] toByteArray( object o )
    {
        bool   hasValue = !( o is DBNull );
        byte[] value    = ( hasValue ? (byte[]) o : (byte[]) null ) ;
        return value;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion downcast to Byte[]

    #region downcast to int

    public static int CastAsInt( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toInt( row[index] ) ;
    }
    public static int CastAsInt( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toInt( row[columnName] ) ;
    }

    public static int? CastAsIntNullable( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toIntNullable( row[index] );
    }
    public static int? CastAsIntNullable( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toIntNullable( row[columnName] ) ;
    }

    #region conversion helpers

    private static int toInt( object o )
    {
        int value = (int)o;
        return value;
    }

    private static int? toIntNullable( object o )
    {
        bool hasValue = !( o is DBNull );
        int? value    = ( hasValue ? (int?) o : (int?) null ) ;
        return value;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion downcast to int

    #region downcast to decimal

    public static decimal CastAsDecimal( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toDecimal( row[index] ) ;
    }
    public static decimal CastAsDecimal( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toDecimal( row[columnName] ) ;
    }

    public static decimal? CastAsDecimalNullable( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toDecimalNullable( row[index] );
    }
    public static decimal? CastAsDecimalNullable( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toDecimalNullable( row[columnName] ) ;
    }

    #region conversion helpers

    private static decimal toDecimal( object o )
    {
        decimal value = (decimal)o;
        return value;
    }

    private static decimal? toDecimalNullable( object o )
    {
        bool     hasValue = !( o is DBNull );
        decimal? value    = ( hasValue ? (decimal?) o : (decimal?) null ) ;
        return value;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion downcast to decimal


    #region downcast to double

    public static double CastAsDouble( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toDouble( row[index] ) ;
    }
    public static double CastAsDouble( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toDouble( row[columnName] ) ;
    }

    public static double? CastAsDoubleNullable( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toDoubleNullable( row[index] );
    }
    public static double? CastAsDoubleNullable( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toDoubleNullable( row[columnName] ) ;
    }

    #region conversion helpers

    private static double toDouble( object o )
    {
        double value = (double)o;
        return value;
    }

    private static double? toDoubleNullable( object o )
    {
        bool     hasValue = !( o is DBNull );
        double? value    = ( hasValue ? (double?) o : (double?) null ) ;
        return value;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion downcast to double

    #region downcast to bool

    public static bool CastAsBool( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toBool( row[index] ) ;
    }
    public static bool CastAsBool( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toBool( row[columnName] ) ;
    }

    public static bool? CastAsBoolNullable( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toBoolNullable( row[index] );
    }
    public static bool? CastAsBoolNullable( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toBoolNullable( row[columnName] ) ;
    }

    #region conversion helpers

    private static bool toBool( object o )
    {
        bool value = (bool)o;
        return value;
    }

    private static bool? toBoolNullable( object o )
    {
        bool  hasValue = !( o is DBNull );
        bool? value    = ( hasValue ? (bool?) o : (bool?) null ) ;
        return value;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion downcast to bool

    #region downcast to string

    public static string CastAsString( this DataRow row , int index )
    {
        return toString( row[index] );
    }
    public static string CastAsString( this DataRow row , string columnName )
    {
        return toString( row[columnName] );
    }

    #region conversion helpers

    private static string toString( object o )
    {
        bool   hasValue = !( o is DBNull );
        string value    = ( hasValue ? (string) o : (string) null ) ;
        return value;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion downcast to string

}
```